# How can I automatically connect to Bitbucket as different users for different repos?

Tags: git, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I'm currently using Bitbucket for both work and personal projects. The problem is that I have two different Bitbucket users I log in as to access and commit to the repos I use for work and the repos I use for my personal projects.

I use one SSH key pair for the work repos and another SSH key pair for my personal repos. However, when I run the following command, I always see that I'm logged into Bitbucket under my work user:

```
ssh -vT git@bitbucket.com
```

As a result, I cannot push or pull from my personal Bitbucket repos from the command line. How can I set up my repos so that it automatically always pushes and pulls work repos as my work Bitbucket user and personal repos as my personal Bitbucket user? Thank you.

Comment: Different gitconfig files?

Comment: matt, could you please be more specific? Each repo has its own `gitconfig` file, but still, when I try to push or pull from my personal repos, I get `Forbidden` errors. I'm setting the remote and everything.

Comment: Basically, from the local repo, I ran `git init`. Then, I ran `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:personal-bitbucket-user-name/personal-bitbucket-repo-name.git`, and then `git push -u origin master`, but it always fails on the last one. The SSH public key is already in BB for my personal accoun too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbitbucket%5D+%5Bgit%5D+multiple+accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is with the combination of the unqiue `$HOME/.ssh/config` file and the `reponame/.git/config` file found in a given git repo.

Your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file would look like the following.

```
username@hostname:~$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host bbmine
        HostName bitbucket.org
        User git
        IdentityFile /home/username/.ssh/id_rsamine

Host bbwork
        HostName bitbucket.org
        User git
        IdentityFile /home/usermname/.ssh/id_rsawork
```

In the file `reponame/.git/config` in your git repo you would place a remote section like the following:

```
[remote "bbmineremote"]
        url = bbmine:bitbucketusername/reponame.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/bitbucket/*
```

You could then push and pull branches like

```
git push bbmineremote master
```

or

```
git pull bbmineremote master
```

You can confirm that you have set this up correctly by running the following ssh command

```
username@hostname:~$ ssh bbmine
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
logged in as bitbucketusername

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
```

These `Host` sections in an `.ssh/config` file are kind of like aliases for anything that uses `ssh`, like `git`.

Comment: OregonTrail, thanks a lot for your answer. I ended up using a combination of this answer and the other SO thread linked to above (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbitbucket%5D+%5Bgit%5D+multiple+accounts) simply because I didn't want to have to type the alias every time I get a git push or pull.

Comment: `git push bbmine master` isn't referring to the ssh host, it's referring to the git remote, if you set the remote as a tracking branch for any given branch that you're working on, then you can run `git pull` and `git push` as you normally would.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for that follow-up. I get it.

Comment: I updated the answer to clarify that

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch for how to make a branch track a specific remote